# Onsen's Navigator - pushPage function

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I implemented a controller to store the title of an item and a page link associated with the item.

```
myApp.controller('takeAwayListCtrl', function($scope)
{
$scope.items = [{itemName: 'Pizze', page: 'pizze_takeaway.html'}, {itemName: 'Pasta', page: 'pasta_takeaway.html'}, {itemName: 'Dessert', page: 'dessert_takeaway.html'}];
});
```

While the x.itemName is intrepreted correctly, the following code fails to interpret the page attribute x.page correctly when I pass it to the pushPage function for the navigator.

```
        <script type="text/ons-template" id="takeaway.html">
            <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator">
            <ons-page>
            <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="center">Take Away</div>
            </ons-toolbar>

            <ons-list ng-controller="takeAwayListCtrl">

            <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-repeat="x in items">

            <ons-button ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage( {{x.page}}, { animation : 'slide' } )" modifier="large--quiet">
            {{ x.itemName }}
            </ons-button>
            </ons-list-item>

            </ons-list>

            </ons-page>
            </ons-navigator>
        </script>
```

Do I need to escape something ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to wrap the `x.page` with an `{{ }}`.

Just use it directly like this:

```
<ons-button ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage(x.page, { animation : 'slide' } )"
```

Comment: Why do you need the actual string in the html? The `ng-click` should parse the expression and call the `myNavigator.pushPage(x.page, ..` function with appropiate value.